# Is there a closed form for the product of odd zetas?

Tags: closed-form, zeta-functions

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(2n+1)=\zeta(3)\zeta(5)\cdots$$

I have only managed to prove that this converges due to comparison with Euler's formula for $\zeta(2n)$

Is there a closed form for that product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no **known** closed form. See [OEIS A$080730$](http://oeis.org/A080730), along with [OEIS A$080729$](http://oeis.org/A080729) and [OEIS A$021002$](http://oeis.org/A021002).